# opencv - accessing an image with cv::Point as argument

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an image constructed using `cv::Mat`. Let's say `cv::Mat image;`. I'd like to access this image using `cv::Point pt;` - such a constructor exists in the `cv::Mat` class.

**My question:**

If I wirte `image.at(pt)` in my code, I'll access the point **`(pt.x, pt.y)`** or I'll access the point **`(pt.y, pt.x)`** in the image?

thanks

Comment: this question is answered in the documentation: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html#accessing-pixel-intensity-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually access a `cv::Mat` like this: `cv::Mat::at( <row>, <col> )`. Which means that the first argument (the 'row') will represent the vertical axis, and the second ('col') will represent the horizontal axis.

In your situation, you will therefore access the point **`(pt.y, pt.x)`**.